# Windows Driver Causing BSOD

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I am installing network low wait filter driver (NDIS 6.0 PCAUSA).
As soon as driver getting started system crashing with blue screen of death.

OS:- Windows 7 professional x64.
Processor:- Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3 GenuineIntel 1488 Mhz

Dump analysis below:-

```
"IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)"
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80002c9e3d5, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000000000 

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5
fffff800`02c9e3d5 488b6d00        mov     rbp,qword ptr [rbp]

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  System

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff80000b9e270 -- (.trap 0xfffff80000b9e270)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80002c9e3d5 rsp=fffff80000b9e400 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=fffff80002e6e401  r9=00000000000000c6 r10=fffff80002c61000
r11=fffff80002e6e4d0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe cy
nt!KiTimerWaitTest+0x2a5:
fffff800`02c9e3d5 488b6d00        mov     rbp,qword ptr [rbp] ss:0018:00000000`00000000=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002d030e9 to fffff80002cf4ca0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`00b9e128 fffff800`02d030e9 : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00b9e130 fffff800`02d00ece : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffff00 fffff880`03a83968 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff800`00b9e270 fffff800`02c9e3d5 : ffffffff`fffb6c20 fffffa80`077d2168 fffffa80`077d2060 fffff800`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x44e
fffff800`00b9e400 fffff800`02c9df6d : fffff880`03a83960 fffffa80`077d2168 fffffa80`077d2168 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiTimerWaitTest+0x2a5
fffff800`00b9e480 fffff800`02ca12de : 00000000`5062a643 fffff800`00b9eb18 00000000`000021c5 fffff800`02e49628 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x6d
fffff800`00b9eaf0 fffff800`02ca15a7 : 00000000`185477c3 fffff800`000021c5 fffffa80`0694fb10 00000000`000000c5 : nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x1be
fffff800`00b9eb90 fffff800`02cf822a : fffff800`02e45180 fffff800`02e551c0 00000000`00000001 fffff880`00000001 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x277
fffff800`00b9ec40 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`00b9f000 fffff800`00b99000 fffff800`00b9ec00 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5
fffff800`02c9e3d5 488b6d00        mov     rbp,qword ptr [rbp]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5d010ddc

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> k
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
fffff800`00b9e128 fffff800`02d030e9 nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00b9e130 fffff800`02d00ece nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff800`00b9e270 fffff800`02c9e3d5 nt!KiPageFault+0x44e
fffff800`00b9e400 fffff800`02c9df6d nt!KiTimerWaitTest+0x2a5
fffff800`00b9e480 fffff800`02ca12de nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x6d
fffff800`00b9eaf0 fffff800`02ca15a7 nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x1be
fffff800`00b9eb90 fffff800`02cf822a nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x277
fffff800`00b9ec40 00000000`00000000 nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a
0: kd> !findthebuild
FindTheBuild service not found

*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (a)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If a kernel debugger is available get the stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, bitfield :
    bit 0 : value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
    bit 3 : value 0 = not an execute operation, 1 = execute operation (only on chips which support this level of status)
Arg4: fffff80002c9e3d5, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS:  0000000000000000 

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5
fffff800`02c9e3d5 488b6d00        mov     rbp,qword ptr [rbp]

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xA

PROCESS_NAME:  System

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff80000b9e270 -- (.trap 0xfffff80000b9e270)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80002c9e3d5 rsp=fffff80000b9e400 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=fffff80002e6e401  r9=00000000000000c6 r10=fffff80002c61000
r11=fffff80002e6e4d0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe cy
nt!KiTimerWaitTest+0x2a5:
fffff800`02c9e3d5 488b6d00        mov     rbp,qword ptr [rbp] ss:0018:00000000`00000000=????????????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002d030e9 to fffff80002cf4ca0

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`00b9e128 fffff800`02d030e9 : 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`00b9e130 fffff800`02d00ece : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffff00 fffff880`03a83968 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff800`00b9e270 fffff800`02c9e3d5 : ffffffff`fffb6c20 fffffa80`077d2168 fffffa80`077d2060 fffff800`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x44e
fffff800`00b9e400 fffff800`02c9df6d : fffff880`03a83960 fffffa80`077d2168 fffffa80`077d2168 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiTimerWaitTest+0x2a5
fffff800`00b9e480 fffff800`02ca12de : 00000000`5062a643 fffff800`00b9eb18 00000000`000021c5 fffff800`02e49628 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x6d
fffff800`00b9eaf0 fffff800`02ca15a7 : 00000000`185477c3 fffff800`000021c5 fffffa80`0694fb10 00000000`000000c5 : nt!KiTimerExpiration+0x1be
fffff800`00b9eb90 fffff800`02cf822a : fffff800`02e45180 fffff800`02e551c0 00000000`00000001 fffff880`00000001 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x277
fffff800`00b9ec40 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`00b9f000 fffff800`00b99000 fffff800`00b9ec00 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5
fffff800`02c9e3d5 488b6d00        mov     rbp,qword ptr [rbp]

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  5d010ddc

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xA_nt!KiTimerWaitTest+2a5

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

0: kd> .trap 0xfffff80000b9e270
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff80002c9e3d5 rsp=fffff80000b9e400 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=fffff80002e6e401  r9=00000000000000c6 r10=fffff80002c61000
r11=fffff80002e6e4d0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac pe cy
nt!KiTimerWaitTest+0x2a5:
fffff800`02c9e3d5 488b6d00        mov     rbp,qword ptr [rbp] ss:0018:00000000`00000000=????????????????`
```

Comment: Obviously it is an incompatible driver, not much you can do other than try one that is.

Comment: incompatible driver? how? not getting your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I checked, there is an issue of operating system which was corrupted, some of the system files was not working.After formatting & reinstalling OS it is working fine.
But can be other solution also.
Formatting my device works for me.